# Two modules - maven. Files other than classes

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies, war

I have two modules: a `.war` and a `.jar`.

I tried to add the `.jar` with some classes to the `.war` as a dependency and it works.

But I also want the `.jar` to have a `layout.xml` file like `.war` has but with a different content (I want it to overwrite the `.war`'s layout). Is it possible?

@EDIT
`layout.xml` is a file where my tiles are defined. It contains attributes like header or footer (`.jar's` layout contains also menu, `.war's` doesn't). I tried to put layout file in diffrent directories.
Mayby i show you the structure of my modules:

JAR

-src/main/java
  ____ ...
-src/main/resurces
 ____-META-INF
-src
____-main
-target
-pom.xml

WAR
-src/main/resurces
-src
___-main
______-webapp
_________-WEB-INF

_____________layouts

_______________-layouts.xml
-target

-pom.xml

Comment: What is `layout.xml`? Could explain a bit more what you are trying to do?

Comment: There is no `layout.xml` inside your jar. I am not sure what you want to do here.

Comment: Of course, here I have not `layout.xml`  inside, because i don't know where i should put layout in `jar`. And then i want to overwrite the `.war`'s layout.